# Connect to unknown Socket server over Wifi

Tags: android, sockets, networking, wifi

I have two devices connected to Wifi network (over router or AP).

**First device - Socket server**

- Connected to Wifi router or AP - Knows its own IP address
- Start Socket server on its IP address and port
- Waits for clients

**Second device - Socket client**

- Connected to Wifi router or AP - Knows its own IP address
- Knows Socket server port (code constant)
- Needs IP address of Socket server for connect it

**Problem**

- How to get IP address of socket server in clients app? Client only knows that there is some Socket server in network and knows its port, but IP address is most of time different.
- I think about broadcast (Information about IP address) from socket server to client. How to do it? 
  Thanks a lot in advance.

Server side code:

```
//Connect to wifi...

public class socketStart extends Thread{

    public void run() {
        try {               
            sserver = new ServerSocket(SocketServerPORT);

            while (runServer) {
                Socket tmp = sserver.accept();
                //Read and write over socket ...
```

Client side code:

```
//Connect to wifi..

String ipAddress = "192.168.0.10";//Here manually

public class SocketRead extends AsyncTask<String, String, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... params) {
         try {
              socket = new Socket(ipAddress, SocketServerPORT);
              //Read and write over socket
```

Comment: `socket server have unkown ip address and its not Wifi server.` ? The socket server will know it. The client has to find out. What is a wifi server? Yes broadcasting is ok.

Comment: Sorry. I modified the description to make it more understandable

Comment: There are two possibilities. First if the client knows its own ip lets say 192.168.0.12 it knows the server has something like that too. If it is a small net the client aldo knows that server ip is always in a small range 129.169.0.2-192.168.0.19 and could just try them all until success. The second is broadcasting.